# Insert Wicket value to a JavaScript function in Java

Tags: java, javascript, html, wicket

I am writing a web app using HTML and Wicket.

In my HTML page, I have a small alert script and I need that the wicket will insert a value to the message of the alert. My code is:

#### HTML code:

```
<script>
   function version(){
   alert(<sub wicket:id="version">);
   } 
</script>
<img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="68" height="21" onclick="version()"/>
```

#### Java:

```
add(new Label("version","1.0.0");
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wicket won't process anything within `<script>`. But you can add a JavaScript function via a header contribution in your page class (or any other `Component`).

Wicket 1.5:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.renderJavaScript("function version(){alert('" + "1.0.0" + "');}", "version");
}
```

Wicket 6.0:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript("function version(){alert('" + "1.0.0" + "');}", "version"));
}
```

An alternative is to render a `Label` which outputs the function:

```
add(new Label("script", "function version(){alert('1.0.0');}").setEscapeModelStrings(false));
```

And in your markup

```
<script wicket:id="script" />
<img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="68" height="21" onclick="version()"/>
```

Comment: setEscapeModelStrings sets if component must replace "sensible" characters from its model  with their related HTML code. This is done for security reason, i.e. to prevent user from injecting malicious code into our pages.